# Input styling is off using MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to MaterialUI so it's probably something simple.

I have this code:

```
<Container>
    <FormControl>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email address</InputLabel>
          <Input id="email" />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
          <Input id="password" />
        </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
</Container>
```

And I thing I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, but this is my rendered view:

[image]

Obviously it shouldn't look like that. Any idea what I messed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap FormGroup and FormControl

```
<FormGroup>
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email address</InputLabel>
    <Input id="email" />
  </FormControl>
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
    <Input id="password" />
  </FormControl>
</FormGroup>
```